# System.InvalidOperationException: The Task is not in a valid state to be started

Tags: c#, xamarin, task

```
Task t = navigation.PushModalAsync(new AuthLoginPage("facebook"));
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();
```

How to resolve the exception : System.InvalidOperationException: The Task is not in a valid state to be started.

Comment: Well, what state is it in? Have you looked at `t`? Also, in general, you should only be manually waiting on tasks when you're running without a synchronization context.

Comment: Usually, a task returned from a call to a ....Async() method is already started. Just remove the call `t.Start()`. Also, consider using the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple usage :-

```
// When you wanted to start the Async call.
var t = navigation.PushModalAsync(new AuthLoginPage("facebook"));
.
.
// do your other work.
.
.
.
// when you want the result of the Task t that you have started before.
var result =await t; // task will wait here for getting result for you.
```

You can read more about async/await. it is good to know more about async/await as it is very powerful and easy. look [**Here for async/await**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh191443.aspx)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a method returns a Task, it has already started, so you don't need to explicitly start it.

If you want to wait on its result, utilize await => `await t;`. If you want to block on its execution, then call the Result property => `t.Result`.